# How do I use a python table?

Tags: python

I was requested by my teacher to write a program in python which would require visitors of said attraction to insert the number of family members they are visiting with, and based off of that, have them know the admission fee. The admission fees given were $25 for anybody under 16, and 40 for anybody over 40.
This is what I've got so far:

```
def main():
    admission = 0
    print("Welcome to Wally World - use this program to calculate your admission fees")
    number = int(input("How many members will you be taking with you? "))
    members = {}
    for n in range(0,number):
        age = int(input("Please enter your ages: "))
        if age <= 16:
            admission = 25
        if age > 16:
            admission = 40

main()
```

How would I go about grabbing said admission values and adding them all together?
Thank you!

Comment: You started `admission` at 0 already, so you can just add to it with `admission += 25` and `admission += 40`. But if the admission fees are $25 for under 16 and $40 for over 40, what about the 16–40 age group?

Comment: What do you mean by 'python table'? @Ryan Looking at his code it seems like a typo in his text.

Comment: Check my answer and do comment if it is not correct, or accept it as correct answer if its. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to use `members = {}`
2. Admissions can be added with only single line conditional statement ([ternary if-else](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)).
3. Check whether number of person is not negative or zero (I've used `exit()` in this case).
4. Check whether age is not negative (I've put `pass` you may call your program again using `main()` or exit using `exit()`).

Here is the working code:

```
def main():
    admission = 0
    print("Welcome to Wally World - use this program to calculate your admission fees")
    number = int(input("How many members will you be taking with you? "))
    if number < 0: exit()
    for n in range(0,number):
        age = int(input("Please enter your ages: "))
        admission += (25 if age <= 16 and age > -1 else 40 if age> 16 else 0)
    return admission

main()
```

Comment: The line `admission += (25 if age <= 16 and age > -1 else 40)` adds 40 if age is lower then 0.

Comment: @A.Grieco Fixed it now.